# C# HwndSource from Process.MainWindowHandle

Tags: c#, interop, message, hwnd

I am trying to "hook" in to the messages of a window to detect a minimize/maximize. I've looked around, and think that the only/best solution to do this, is to hook into the messages of a window, and check for the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message, and then check it's status.

I've run into a problem.

```
System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource source = System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.FromHwnd(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0].MainWindowHandle);
System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceHook hook = new System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceHook(WndProc);
source.AddHook(hook);
```

It will give me a "Object refrence not set to the instance of an object." error on "source.AddHook...". When breakpointing, it also becomes clear that the source variable is null. In other words: It fails to get the HwndSource on the first line.

I know that it's possible by using an "WindowInteropHelper", but that is when you have the actual window as a Windows.Window available, but in my situation I do not.

Any workarounds/solutions would be very much appreciated,
René Sackers

**P.S. I am 100% sure that Notepad is running when the code is executed, and it manages to find it, and it's main window handle.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`HwndSource` and `HwndSourceHook` don't do what you are thinking.  They only exist for interop between WPF and standard Win32 windows - in the same process.  They can't be used for hooking the window procedure of a window in a different process.

HwndSource.FromHwnd() doesn't create a new HwndSource object it "Returns the HwndSource object of the specified window."  If the hWnd doesn't have one it associated, `FromHwnd()` will return null.  It would be like calling `System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle` on the hWnd from notepad - which would return null as well since the notepad window isn't a WinForms control.

The way to hook another process's window procedure is to use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  And for to hook another process, [the code has to be written in C or C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804).

Comment: Alright, that clarifies some stuff, thank you. I was already thinking about SetWindowsHookEx, but have some bad experiences with that starting with keyboard and mouse hooks disconnecting. I'll give it a shot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `WindowInteropHelper`. The documentation for the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.windowinterophelper.aspx) states:

> Initializes a new instance of the WindowInteropHelper class for a specified Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) window.

The notepad window is not a WPF window which is why `FromHwnd` returns `null`.

In fact, I don't believe it could ever work for a window in a separate process, even if the other window was a WPF window.